# Server error when accessing site via DNS/Load balancer "geolitedbpath ain't presented in web.comfig"

Tags: kentico

When on the server where the site is running, it works fine, and no errors show in event log. When hitting via DNS or IP (which is to the load balancer), server error occurs regarding geolitedbpath

I've commented out the reference to this library in the app settings, commented out the calls in the packages.config file, and afaik our application isn't specifically using this. We've run our website for 10+ years and from the point I started, have always seen this error, but never to the point of causing a server error.

This is a new build of K12 portal on new Windows 2016 servers/IIS 10 with plenty of resources etc. The site is a copy of the filesystem of current production which is working.

This is the error in the event logs.

Description:
Message: geolitedbpath ain't presented in web.comfig
Parameter name: geolitedbpath

Exception type: System.ArgumentException
Stack trace:
at CMS.Mvc.Core.GeoProviders.GeoInfoProvider..ctor()
at Global.WriteStateCodeToTheSession(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.CallEventHandler[TArgs](EventHandler`1 h, TArgs e) at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.Raise[TArgs](String partName, List`1 list, TArgs e, Boolean important)
at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler`2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e) at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler`2.StartEvent(TArgs e)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState()
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with the load balancer assigning a profile with no configuration .. setting LB to pass-thru resolved the issue.